# IBM CDC on i-series (source)

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-data-replication

I am working in a new testing environment for CDC (data replication) capturing data from AS400 (i-series) with a 11.4.0.  Unfortunately, it is not connected for the installation by a user with QSECOFR and D_MIRROR is leaving to be created.

When trying to connect the datastore, it prompt me for the password.  So, I tried to put QSECOFR to logon but re-prompt me again.  So, I have asked the AS400 administrator to change the D_MIRROR user profile with password.  It is fine for the logon process but not able to map the subscription with the error.

ERROR:
The mapping for target table  could not be completed because the definition of the source table does not exist in the target datastore. This may be caused by an incomplete describe. Check the event log for related events and a possible cause.

I am not sure what I should do next.

Answer (score 1):

D_MIRROR user profile is created automatically during CDC installation, which is used by CDC to monitor replication activities. D_MIRROR user profile should not be used for login purposes.
Please refer to this documentation :

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.cdcfori.doc/concepts/specifyingd_mirroruserprofile.html

In future if you face "Unable to complete table mapping with DMU0068 error" please check the document at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/536525.

Hope this will address problem you are seeing.

Thank you
Sudarshan K

Answer (score 0):

Remove the TEST install and re-install the TEST with User which has QSECOFR privileges and run it thru, make sure you leave the D_MIRROR profile untouch and you should be able to create the instance sucessfully, Once created use the TSSETREG to set the susbsyetm and start the describe process it should work well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).